# How do I run my python file within another python file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, python-requests

I have the following:

```
# script_1

from ephem import *
import time, math, commands, sys, os

elements = open('orbital_elements.txt')

# Then does some stuff and takes information from the text file, calculating diff_x, diff_y, diff_z

return diff_x, diff_y, diff_z
```

I then have a second script. This script imports script_1 as a module and then will loop over a range, each time altering orbital_elements.txt and running script_1 on the new text file to return new values of diff_x, diff_y, diff_z each time:

```
#script_2

from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import script_1

df_input = pd.read_csv("sampling.txt", sep = ",", index_col=False)

def convert(x):
    # Input single row of df_input

    epoch_osculation = '2018 02 22'
    M = x['M']
    AOP = x['AOP']
    LOAN = x['LOAN']
    INCL = x['INCL']
    e = x['e']
    a = x['a']

    text_file = open("orbital_elements.txt", "w")
    text_file.write("Object: 1 ceres\n")
    text_file.write("Epoch of osculation     =  " + str(epoch_osculation) + "\n")
    text_file.write("Mean anomaly            =  " + str(M) + "\n")
    text_file.write("Argument of perihelion  =   " + str(AOP) + "\n")
    text_file.write("Long. of ascending node =   " + str(LOAN) + "\n")
    text_file.write("Inclination             =   " + str(INCL) + "\n")
    text_file.write("Eccentricity            =  " + str(e) + "\n")
    text_file.write("Semimajor axis          =  " + str(a))
    text_file.close()

index = np.arange(len(df_input))
df_output = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x', 'y', 'z'], index = index)

for i in range(len(df_input)):
    # Creates text file for script_2.py
    convert(df_input.iloc[i]) 

    script_1

    # Record data in a table
    #df_output['x'][i] = script_1.diff_x
    #df_output['y'][i] = script_1.diff_y
    #df_output['z'][i] = script_1.diff_z
```

Unfortunately, each time that I run the second script it is returning the same values as if the text file orbital_elements.txt hadn't been altered.

I know that the text file is updating each time as I have tested that. The issue seems to lie in script_1 not recognising the updated version of orbital_elements.txt and returning the same values each time.

How did I adjust it so that the first script, when imported into script_2, will take into account the updated version of orbital_elements.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body of script_1 **will run as soon as it is imported:**

```
from ephem import *
import time, math, commands, sys, os

elements = open('orbital_elements.txt')

# Then does some stuff and takes information from the text file, calculating diff_x, diff_y, diff_z

return diff_x, diff_y, diff_z
```

So all of the above code runs immediately at:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import script_1   # <- This line
```

You need to put the code into a function and only call it when appropriate:

```
from ephem import *
import time, math, commands, sys, os

def main():
    elements = open('orbital_elements.txt')

    # Then does some stuff and takes information from the text file, calculating diff_x, diff_y, diff_z

    return diff_x, diff_y, diff_z
```

Then use `script_1.main()` when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try closing the file. I do think it's the problem.

```
# script_1

from ephem import *
import time, math, commands, sys, os

elements = open('orbital_elements.txt')

# Then does some stuff and takes information from the text file, calculating diff_x, diff_y, diff_z
elements.close()
return diff_x, diff_y, diff_z
```

Comment: Hmm, it's still returning the same values.

Comment: Actually try closing the file before return. I got it on the wrong line.

Comment: It's better to do that in a `with` statement, you'd make less mistakes like that

Comment: How should I use a with statement?

Comment: `with open('something', 'w') as f:
    f.write('something')`

@MattHill